# How to get assembly information of a web application converted from web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I had a website project which I converted to a web application, now I am trying to display dll version information of my web application. I tried

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() which returns App_Web_ehipvj25, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 

Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() which returns system.web assembly

Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() which returns null
```

And the actual version info which comes from `AssemblyInfo.cs`, is 2.0.*

when I created a new application and tried `getExecutingAssembly` method it worked correctly and showed myapplicationname **Version=2.0.1213.3432** as result  but in the application which converted from website results **0.0.0.0** what action might have caused this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out how to get version info

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("assemblyname").GetName().Version.ToString()
```